# Why there is space in latex equation

Tags: equations

I have this equation in latex.

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:eq0043}
Z{^\prime}_{n+1} = TBMSA(LF(Z_{n})) 
\end{equation}
```

But it's displayed with space between M and S. I'm not sure why.

[image]

Comment: Do you want `Z'_{n+1} = \mathit{TBMSA}(\mathit{LF}(Z_{n}))` maybe (although I am unsure whether the letters should be italicizsed)?

Comment: What do `TBMSA` and `LF` stand for? Are they acronyms? Variable names?

Comment: To be a bit more explicit than the answers, the problem is that `TBMSA` is the variable `T`, times the variable `B`, times the variable `M`, ....  Because it is five separate variables, they are spread out a bit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Math italic is designed with wide sidebearings to separate the letters so they do not look like a word, as adjacent letters usually denote multiplication of 1-letter variables. Use `\mathrm{TBSMSA}` to typeset the name in a font designed for words.  Also `Z{^\prime}` should be `Z'`  You are superscripting an empty node to the right of the Z, not the Z itself .

Answer (score 15):

I think there are two separate issues with your code.

- Do replace `Z{^\prime}_{n+1}` with either `Z^{\prime}_{n+1}` or, more succinctly, `Z'_{n+1}`.
- While `$TBMSA$` and `$LF$` clearly are not right, more information is needed to determine what *is* right, typographically speaking.

  - If `TBMSA` and `LF` are acronyms, it's best to typeset them in upright (aka "roman") mode.
  - On the other hand, if `TBMSA` and `LF` are multi-letter variable names, you may want to wrap them in `\mathit` directives.

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

$Z{^\prime}_{n+1}$ $Z^{\prime}_{n+1}$ $Z'_{n+1}$

\medskip
$TBMSA(LF(Z_{n}))$ $\mathit{TBMSA}(\mathit{LF}(Z_{n}))$ $\mathrm{TBMSA}(\mathrm{LF}(Z_{n}))$
\end{document}
```